# Step voltage down via voltage divider, then grab original voltage output

Tags: voltage, pressure

I have a pressure sensor that takes 5v and outputs a voltage based on pressure, however the input that I read cannot exceed 1.8V due to limitations of the board that I am using. Thus I was wondering how I could lower the output yet still read the correct value from the sensor... The transfer function of the sensor is: Vout = Vs*(0.0012858*P+0.04) ± Error

Comment: Your topic suggests a voltage divider - that's the right approach.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: The input to the pressure sensor is 5V. The input to my pin, which is the output of the sensor should not exceed 1.8V

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 'P' is the pressure, you can reason to yourself what the maximum pressure is that you expect it to bear. That lets you calculate the maximum Vout, call it Vout(max).

You can then scale the voltage down using a 2-resistor potential divider. As you know what Vout(max) is so you're scaling that down to 1.8 V.

This all assumes that your 1.8 V input is an analogue input and not digital. If the latter, you can only determine if the sensor is above or below a threshold. You'd then best use a comparator so that your trip point is clean and you can add hysteresis to ensure noise-free switching.

Comment: How would I figure out the pressure from the scaled down voltage (i.e. max voltage without the divider would be 4.7 which would represent max pressure). With the divider, max voltage would be 1.8. How would I equate 1.8 to max pressure?

Comment: Would I just use 0.38, i.e. 1.8V / 5V = 0.38 Then divide whatever voltage I get... So 2.5V would be dropped to 0.95V. So I would divide 0.95V by 0.38 and plug into the transfer function to solve for P?

Comment: A resistor divider may not work if the analog input is not buffered. Most ADCs have an input impedance that is not constant with input voltage, thus affecting the divider. As an example, you can't use a resistor divider with any of the BeagleBones (which has 1.8v analog inputs). @TonyM.

Comment: Depends upon the signal strength out of the divider and therefore what current it can afford down the divider versus the ADC input current, @Mark. But a buffer op-amp can be added if it gets to that.

Comment: @sparkart, only if your sensor range is 0..5 V.  Otherwise if the range is less, you're wasting some precision, which may or may not matter but is not good design practice. What's the maximum pressure 'P' that the sensor will undergo? Ta.

Comment: @TonyM0  max pressure is: 700 kPa

Comment: @sparkart, thanks. So if you push that through your equation above, what does that make your Vout(max)? Secondly, what is your 1.8 V input going to, specifically? Cheers.

Comment: Hi @TonyM. You said "Depends upon the signal strength out of the divider and therefore what current it can afford down the divider versus the ADC input current". True. But the impedance of the ADC will be in parallel with the resistance of the bottom resistor, so if the ADC impedance varies, the whole divider ratio varies. The goal would be to have the bottom resistor's value low enough that the ADCs impedance is negligible, but as you said, the signal strength of the sensor would need to be high enough to support a low impedance load. Most sensors have a pretty high impedance output.

Comment: Hi there @Mark. It does depend on the sensor but if, for example, its output can drive 10 mA, your divider resistors could be 640R and 360R with 5 mA going down them. You could then afford 50 uA out of that for your ADC, about a 100K load, and that would be 1 % of the 5 mA. Those are FSD values, of course. Does that seem fair for an ADC and would some variation in ADC input current not disturb the ADC result much? I'm doing this without the aid of a data sheet :-)

Comment: @TonyM the 1.8V would be going into ADC input of a beaglebone board. 4.7*0.38= 5*(0.0012858*700+0.04) = Vout = 1.78

Comment: @sparkart, getting closer. What's the output current capability of your sensor?

Comment: @TonyM, it is 10mAdc